# compressing css3-pie

Tags: internet-explorer, css3pie

In the documentation it said that gzipping the pie.htc is possible, but no clues on how to do it. Now how can I gzip the .htc file and let the browser know that it's compressed?(As I remember, doing the same thing was possible for .js files.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fastest approach is to just compress everything server has to output.

apache:

```
<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
# Enable the module
mod_gzip_on yes 
# Allow GZIP compression for all requests 
mod_gzip_item_include mime .?
</IfModule>


# Method 2: Compress all content, manually excluding specified file types
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # place filter 'DEFLATE' on all outgoing content
  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  # exclude uncompressible content via file type
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:gif|jpe?g|png|rar|zip)$ no-gzip
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # properly handle requests coming from behind proxies
    Header append Vary User-Agent
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```